# Windows 10 Ruby on Rails Install Issue Json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

Hello I am trying set up ruby on rails on my pc.  Everytime i do a bundle install, I receive this error

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.

I am trying to use ruby 2.2.3, This is my first experience using Ruby on my pc.

Answer (score 4):

Some gems need to build some native `C/C++` extensions. You should install `DevKit`. Here's the [link](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/). And then add it to your system environment's path variable.